# Installing LizardTech GeoExpress Command Line Applications on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, mrsid

I need to convert MrSid files so I can view them as TIFFs in QGIS.  I am trying to install the LizardTech GeoExpress Command Line Applications available [here](https://www.lizardtech.com/gis-tools/tools-and-utilities) to do the conversions.  I have downloaded the correct Linux 64-bit version, and extracted the contents to a directory on the hard-drive.  The included read-me file states this...*These utilities dynamically load libraries that are also installed.
Please ensure that your LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable includes the directory to
which this package is installed.*

I am new to Linux and found this command online to map to the tools:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/media/gerry/02689296-24e3-4e9b-b940-b33bdbbcab43/GIS/OtherSoftware/GeoExpressCLUtils-9.5.0.4326-linux64"
```

When I try to run a simple example I get this...

```
mrsidgeoinfo ortho_1-1_1n_s_wa073_2013_1.sid
mrsidgeoinfo: command not found
```

I am not too clear on on how to install these utilities. How do I install the LizardTech GeoExpress Command Line Applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which is an environment variable you set to tell the run-time shared library loader (ld.so) where to look when searching for shared libraries that aren't installed to the standard locations. However the directions Lizardtech give are incorrect.

Also, you haven't told your shell where the executables are, i.e the command line applications in the `GeoExpressCLUtils-9.5.0.4326-linux64/bin` subdirectory, which you specify by setting the `PATH` env. var.

Finally, you need to make the commandline applications executable.

Try:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/media/gerry/02689296-24e3-4e9b-b940-b33bdbbcab43/GIS/OtherSoftware/GeoExpressCLUtils-9.5.0.4326-linux64/bin:/media/gerry/02689296-24e3-4e9b-b940-b33bdbbcab43/GIS/OtherSoftware/GeoExpressCLUtils-9.5.0.4326-linux64/libproject

export PATH=$PATH:/media/gerry/02689296-24e3-4e9b-b940-b33bdbbcab43/GIS/OtherSoftware/GeoExpressCLUtils-9.5.0.4326-linux64/bin

chmod +x /media/gerry/02689296-24e3-4e9b-b940-b33bdbbcab43/GIS/OtherSoftware/GeoExpressCLUtils-9.5.0.4326-linux64/bin/ mrsid*
chmod +x /media/gerry/02689296-24e3-4e9b-b940-b33bdbbcab43/GIS/OtherSoftware/GeoExpressCLUtils-9.5.0.4326-linux64/bin/ lidar*

mrsidgeoinfo ortho_1-1_1n_s_wa073_2013_1.sid
```

Comment: @Luke- the first two lines execute without error but    mrsidgeoinfo ortho_1-1_1n_s_wa073_2013_1.sid   returns       mrsidgeoinfo: command not found

Comment: @GBG see edit with fix

Comment: Thanks, for the insight.  This worked. gerry@gerrypc:~$ chmod +x /home/gerry/ortho_1-1_1n_s_wa073_2013_1.sid
gerry@gerrypc:~$ mrsidgeoinfo ortho_1-1_1n_s_wa073_2013_1.sid

Comment: Put on hold?  Really?  Converting mrsids to geotiffs using command line utililites so you can view them in QGIS is off-topic in GIS SackExchange?

Comment: @GBG you can ask about the hold in meta. You shouldn't need to make your data (.sid) executable.